# Inductive lifting

Tags: haskell, typeclass, applicative

I would like to combine the various lifts into a single class

```
class Lift a b where
  lift :: a -> b
```

So that `lift` can be used in place of `fmap`, `liftA2`, `liftA3`, etc.

Now it is easy enough to write the instances for these:

```
instance Functor f => Lift (a -> b) (f a -> f b) where
  lift = fmap
instance Applicative f => Lift (a -> b -> c) (f a -> f b -> f c) where
  lift = liftA2
instance Applicative f => Lift (a -> b -> c -> d) (f a -> f b -> f c -> f d) where
  lift = liftA3
```

However for `liftA2` and beyond there is an inductive property.  That is we can derive a lift from smaller lifts.  For example:

```
liftA2 f a b       = (liftA  f a)       <*> b
liftA3 f a b c     = (liftA2 f a b)     <*> c
liftA4 f a b c d   = (liftA3 f a b c)   <*> d
liftA5 f a b c d e = (liftA4 f a b c d) <*> e
...
```

So I would like to instead of enumerating each lift as a separate instances use induction to make all of them.  However while the definition is inductive I have trouble expressing the relationship between one lift and the next *algebraically*.  That is while I can describe it, it is not a combination of `lift`s and simple combinators.

Even if I rewwrite them point free we can see that each level is more complex that the last:

```
liftA2 = ((<*>) .) . liftA
liftA3 = (((<*>) .) .) . liftA2
liftA4 = ((((<*>) .) .) .) . liftA3
liftA5 = (((((<*>) .) .) .) .) . liftA4
...
```

Now I think that this could be worked around by adding a ghc natural to the class

```
class Lift (n :: Nat) (a :: Type) (b :: Type) | a b -> n  where
  lift :: a -> b
```

And then using a supporting type class to do a lot of the connective work.  However this solution would be far from elegant and I view it mostly as a last resort since I would rather no bloat the class with a `Nat` used only for computation.

Is there a way I inductively define `lift` without changing the class definition like this?

Comment: Have you tried actually using your `Lift` defined the brute force way? I would expect you to have trouble...

Comment: @luqui Have trouble in what way?  Aside from some initial confusion I had it seems to work perfectly.

Comment: @SriotchilismO'Zaic You may find [this post on ‘_n_-ary functors’](http://gelisam.blogspot.com/2017/12/n-ary-functors.html) useful.

Comment: So `lift foldr (Just (:)) (Just []) (Just [1,2,3])` works? (On my phone, otherwise I'd check it myself)